# How can I put section between 2 horizontal lines

Tags: sectioning

Could anyone tell me how can I put section between 2 horizontal lines.

I tried something similar to the following code but it did not work.

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{‎
    \hrule
    \@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
        {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
        {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
        {\large\scshape}‎‎
    \protect ‎\hrule
}
\makeatother
```

this is a sample picture for `‎‎\section{Experience}‎`

[image: sample]

Comment: Should the section be numbered?

Comment: @Bernard: no only the title is important

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We can exploit the fact that the final argument of `\@startsection` in the definition of `\section` can contain a one parameter macro which will receive the section title (with the number) as argument.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{%
  \@startsection{section}{1}
    {\z@}%
    {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
    {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
    {\ruled@title}%
}
\newcommand{\ruled@title}[1]{%
  \vbox{\hrule\vskip2pt\hbox{\large\scshape #1}\vskip2pt\hrule}%
}
\makeatother

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-2}

\begin{document}
\section{experience}

Whatever you want to tell about your experience.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just emphasizing the feature: mine and this one don't support multiple lines of section title.

Answer (score 4):

Another simple but not perfect solution.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\def\Section#1{\section*{\tabular{@{}c@{}}\hline #1\\\hline \endtabular}}
\begin{document}
\Section{PSTricks is fun!}
Bla bla bla
\end{document}
```

[image]